# LaTeX Contents page for my dissertation

Tags: table-of-contents

Trying to format my contents page to allow me to start my introduction at a page one. It is an engineering dissertation. How do i set my table of contents so the introduction starts at page one and the title numbers follow chronologically? i want machine vision for example to say 2.1 machine vision. and all the subheadings to have a decimal point. I am using chapters but is a report layout?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It will be way easier for others to help you if you copy your code here rather than adding a picture. The idea is that this way, others will be able to copy your code, compile it, and improve it to solve your problem.

Comment: Maybe try using `\pagenumbering{roman}` at the beginning of your document, then `\pagenumbering{arabic}`just before the introduction: this resets the page numbering.

Comment: @Bernard -- It would also be a good thing to put `\newpage` before `\pagenumbering{arabic}`, and also `\setcounter{page}{1}` just after that.

Comment: \cleardoublepage would be even better than \newpage

Answer (score 2):

The most elegant solution for this is use  `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` that have an obvious structure meaning and take of care of change automatically the format and reset of the page counter, but these commands are not defined in `report`. It is rather unclear in your question, but it seems that you really want the format of a  book, so my suggestion is change the document class to a  book-like class, as `memoir` or `scrbook`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter    
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
Lore ipsum ...
\end{document}
```